# Healpy query_polygon RuntimeError: Unknown exception

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

I'm using `healpy.query_polygon` to get a list of healpix indexes inside a polygon. According to the documentation:

> vertices: Vertex array containing the vertices of the polygon, shape (N, 3).

But when I try to get all indexes from the following polygon, a `RuntimeError: Unknown exception` appears:

In[1]:

```
import healpy as hp

vertex_array = np.array([[0.65, -0.04, 0.76], [0.58, 0.38, 0.72], [0.91, -0.29, 0.31],[0.91, 0.18, 0.38]])

print(vertex_array.shape)
vertex_array
```

Out[1]:

```
(4, 3)
array([[ 0.65, -0.04,  0.76],
       [ 0.58,  0.38,  0.72],
       [ 0.91, -0.29,  0.31],
       [ 0.91,  0.18,  0.38]])
```

In[2]:

```
healpix_indexes_test = hp.query_polygon(4, vertex_array)
```

Out[2]:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-5a14f69cb078> in <module>
----> 1 healpix_indexes_test = hp.query_polygon(4, vertex_array)

healpy/src/_query_disc.pyx in healpy._query_disc.query_polygon()

RuntimeError: Unknown exception
```

[Here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/edpd5pbs) you can see visualisation of these dots lying on a sphere.

Just for fun I tried to transpose the input array, so its shape became  (3, 4). The `Unknown exception` problem disappeared. But input like this contradict the documentation, so I don't believe it.

In[1]:

```
print(vertex_array.T.shape)
vertex_array.T
```

Out[1]:

```
(3, 4)
array([[ 0.65,  0.58,  0.91,  0.91],
       [-0.04,  0.38, -0.29,  0.18],
       [ 0.76,  0.72,  0.31,  0.38]])
```

In[2]:

```
healpix_indexes_test_1 = hp.query_polygon(4, vertex_array.T)

healpix_indexes_test_1
```

Out[2]:

```
array([ 42,  58,  75, 107, 123, 140])
```

I'll be gratefull for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

With the [help](https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/549) of Healpy members on Github, the solution was found. It's important to define the order of the vertices correctly. In my case it means that the last two dot's coordinates should be swopped to make the rectangle simple, not self-crossing:

In[1]:

```
vertex_array_fixed = np.array([[0.65, -0.04, 0.76], [0.58, 0.38, 0.72], [0.91, 0.18, 0.38], [0.91, -0.29, 0.31]])

print(vertex_array_fixed.shape)
vertex_array_fixed
```

Out[1]:

```
(4, 3)
array([[ 0.65, -0.04,  0.76],
       [ 0.58,  0.38,  0.72],
       [ 0.91,  0.18,  0.38],
       [ 0.91, -0.29,  0.31]])
```

In[2]:

```
healpix_indexes_test = hp.query_polygon(4, vertex_array_fixed)

healpix_indexes_test
```

Out[2]:

```
array([24, 40, 71])
```

**Here comes the visualisation:**

In[3]:

```
Nside = 2048

healpix_indexes_test = hp.query_polygon(Nside, vertex_array_fixed)

healpix_indexes_test
```

Out[3]:

```
array([ 5968575,  5968576,  5968577, ..., 17387119, 17387120, 17395310])
```

In[4]:

```
Npix = hp.nside2npix(Nside)

whole_map = np.arange(Npix, dtype=float)
whole_map[healpix_indexes_test] = hp.UNSEEN

hp.mollview(m, title="Fixed rectangle")
```

Out[4]:
[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8siY.png)